# Sequelize query with NOT LIKE where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I create a sql query involving a `WHERE NOT LIKE` clause using Sequelize.js(Version 1.7.0)? The final SQL query should look like this

SELECT *  FROM `transfers` WHERE `address` NOT LIKE '%bank%'

This is the code that I have

```
findToProcess: function(callback) {
      var query;
      query = {
        where: {
          status: 1
          address: 'Bank Address',

        },
        order: [["created_at", "ASC"]]
      };
      return Transfer.findAll(query).complete(callback);
```

Squelize version 2, such a query can be made using `$notLike: '%hat'` operator. Sadly I can't update my sequelize version. Is there any way to get this done using sequelize v1.7.0?

Comment: What is the reason you can't upgrade, because that does seem like the most obvious solution -- if there's a feature missing from the version you're using and it exists in a newer version then you need to use the newer version. It's unlikely that anyone is going to back-port it into the old version for you.

Comment: I am working on a client's project and the client is adamant that no packages shall be updated as somebody have convinced him it would break a lot of 'stuff' .

Answer (score 4):

Sequelize Query We have achive to follow [sequelize document](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html) use given examples

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
where: { status: 1,
       address: {
        [Op.like]: '%hat', // LIKE '%hat'
        [Op.notLike]: '%hat'// NOT LIKE '%hat'
       }
    }
```